# Symfony 4 - Easyadmin and full package CKEditor

Tags: symfony, symfony4, ckeditor4.x, easyadmin, symfony-4.2

I'm trying to install the full package from CDEditor 4 to use it with easyadmin, but even if I manually install CKEditor, I keep the basic package on easyadmin.

[Actual CKeditor interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDSaw.png)

In my fos_ckeditor, I just have:

```
fos_ck_editor:
 base_path: "ckeditor"
  js_path:   "ckeditor/ckeditor.js"


twig:
 form_themes:
    - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
```

I found this in the symfony documentation for FOSCkeditor. But I found nothing about easyadmin and custom CKEditor version.

Could anyone help me about that please?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing CKEditor in your Symfony project, you must edit your settings if you wish to have the full editor available to you:

**config/packages/fos_ck_editor.yaml**

```
fos_ck_editor:
    configs:
        my_config:
            toolbar: full //other values are 'standard' and 'basic'
```

You can find more information about those settings in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/usage/toolbar.html).

Comment: Thank you I was watching the wrong documentation so ... Ty